# After deleting Bootcamp .. I failed to merge free disk space using Disk Utility

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, diskutil

After deleting Bootcamp partition I cannot merge it back to Macintosh HD partition nor even using it to install windows again.

Using Disk Utility this is what happens:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

I tried to login to MacOS recovery mode and do the same thing.. but still getting the same error..

Output from diskutil list:
[image: Output]

Output from sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
[image: Output]

*I'm Running MacOS 10.13.6 on Retina MacBook Pro Late 2013

Thanks

Comment: Try `sudo  diskutil  apfs  resizeContainer  disk0s2  0`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to David Anderson in the comment section.

I used that terminal command:

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

and it worked!

Thanks again!